# Creating clustered column chart on Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to create clustered column chart on Power BI but I don't know how.

[image: With this data]

I want to create a chart like this

[image: like this].

PS: chart legend as month

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the data in a tabular form? You need to pivot the data with `Power Query`, to show the data like the clustered chart.

Comment: Posted the answer below

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Pivot function in Powerquery to achieve this. We can start with the tabular format like below.

[image]

select BR0* columns as below. these are the columns that we are going to unpivot because cluster chart required row values.

select the highlighted option from below. and select the relevant columns

[image]

It will create a table like below. after click close and apply to apply the changes.

[image]

Get a cluster column chart in PBI and assign the columns as below.

[image]